# 2 different implementations for 1 interface (.h file)

Tags: objective-c

I have a `baseClass1.h` an d `baseClass1.m`

These have several public methods which are used by several base classes. What I am trying to do is to create a different implementation of same methods declarations.

After I have written `baseClass2.m` whose interface is baseClass1.h also.

Now in subclasses, how do I have methods do what I've defined in baseClass2.m instead of their respective definition from baseClass1.m

EDIT:

I duplicated the target in baseClass1 workspace to a new target. Both implementation files are exclusive to 2 targets. What I'm trying to do is to use different .m file with each target selection from xCode.

It is somewhat like changing the AP definitions. To explore the possibility to discard baseClass1.m for given now. Any way so that even if I delete `baseClass1.m` and program should still build

Comment: Are you saying you want to have one single class which, in the same program, has two versions of each identically named method?

Comment: BTW, per Cocoa naming conventions, class names should always start with uppercase letter, whereas methods, variables, and properties generally have names that start with lowercase letters.

Comment: What is the relationship between `BaseClass1` and `BaseClass2`? Is one a subclass of the other? Or do they just happen to share some common interface? Perhaps you can make this less abstract, and give us examples of what these two base classes are and what some of the anticipated subclasses are.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths ..Yes. Need for it arose when we wanted to experiment  some new functionality yet wanted to retain the old one. I understand delegation would've been a good way to do that, but I'm just exploring what could be done with targets. Also I'm editing my answer with brief target info.

Comment: @CalZone: So you want two different implementations of the same class in two different targets?

Comment: @MartinR Yes, precisely.

Answer (score 2):

If you want two different implementations of the same class in two different targets then you can simply use two separate implementation files *for the same class*, and add each of them to one target only, e.g.

- "BaseClass.h": the interface,
- "BaseClassA.m": implementation of `BaseClass`, only in target A,
- "BaseClassB.m": implementation of `BaseClass`, only in target B.

An implementation file need not have the same name as class, that is just a (useful) convention.

Comment: How do I tell subclass which target and implementation to use? Subclass only uses `#import baseclass.h` The subclass in my case is actually in a separate workspace in same project.

Comment: @CalZone: A subclass does not need to know which implementation is used at runtime. You just have to ensure that either "BaseClassA.m" or "BaseClassB.m" is compiled into the target app.

Comment: In the sidebar there's a section for Target Membership. You only include .m files in targets; just make sure the right target is checked for each of BaseClassA/BaseClassB.

Answer (score 1):

You can use protocol to declare common interface.

baseProtocol.h:

```
@protocol your_protocol <NSObject>
@optional
- (void)methodA;
@required
- (void)methodB;
@end
```

baseClass1.h:

```
#import "baseProtocol.h"        
@interface baseClass1 : NSObject<your_protocol>
@end
```

baseClass2.h:

```
#import "baseProtocol.h"
@interface baseClass2 : NSObject<your_protocol>
@end
```

Comment: Thank you @Avt. I could use Delegation but I'm mostly trying to understand how .h and .m files interact with each other. Your link was pretty useful actually.

Answer (score 1):

You need create `@protocol` for common interface.
Implement it's methods in baseClass1 and baseClass2.
And then you can subclass any base class you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Technically this is possible: easy, in fact.

It is also a Bad Idea™.

Why is it a bad idea? Because it is unexpected. It is very unexpected. So unexpected, that some people didn't think it possible, many more didn't even understand what you where asking.

By using this anti-pattern, you are dooming future developer to waste hours trying to figure out what you did, and why you did it.

In this example, just use a protocol, fake it out by using a cluster class, or just support both implementations in a single class using a flag to switch between the two. Don't make things harder on everyone just because you can be clever with the build system.